# remoting error: Because of security restrictions, the type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef cannot be accessed

Tags: .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I use remoting for class AppServerSqlServerDataUtil.

The configuration files:

client:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application >
      <client url="tcp://172.22.110.25:8086">
        <activated  type="DealsRoomDAL.AppServerSqlServerDataUtil, DealsRoomDAL"/>
      </client>     
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" secure="true" >
          <serverProviders>
            <formatter ref="soap" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
          </serverProviders>

        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <customErrors mode="off"/>
    <application>
      <service>
        <activated   type="DealsRoomDAL.AppServerSqlServerDataUtil, DealsRoomDAL"/>
      </service>

      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="8086"  secure="true" machineName="prblalsmtrbx.bnhpgroup.com" >
          <clientProviders>
            <formatter ref="soap" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
          </clientProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

I have a function that gets SqlCommand as a parameter on class AppServerSqlServerDataUtil

```
public object GetScalarValue(SqlCommand com)
        {
          ...
        }
```

When I try to call GetScalarValue I get the error:

Because of security restrictions, the type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef cannot be accessed.

When I call other functions on AppServerSqlServerDataUtil that contain simple input parameters such string there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with SqlCommand parameter.
It is not serializable.
Error message is very confusing though.